# Chrome Extension to fetch URL of current tab and open new tab based on re-writing URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I actually want to use this with a more complex re-write of the URL but for simplicity right now I want to accomplish something more basic.  So if I'm on https://www.google.com and click the button for my extension, I want it open a new tab with http://www.google.com/images

I found separate questions about fetching the URL and opening a new tab, but I haven't been able to find anything about combining the two.

This is what I have right now:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Rewrite",
  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*", "tabs"]
}
```

background.js:

```
var currentURL;

chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  currentURL = tabs[0];
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    var newURL = currentURL + "/images";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

I've tried various forms of this such as having the chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener block nested inside of the chrome.tabs.query block and vice versa but none seem to work.

With the current version, the tab opens but the URL is chrome-extension://bffolfmjagnpglbmjkgajodjlfpekaeo/[object%20Object]/images with a "webpage is not found" error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I figured it out.  It seems to work if I add '.url' after tabs[0] in background.js:

```
var currentURL;

chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  currentURL = tabs[0].url;
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    var newURL = currentURL + "/images";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

Although this looks cleaner:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
        var newURL = tabs[0].url + "/images";
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
    });
});
```

Comment: It does not "look cleaner", it's the only correct way. Otherwise, `currentURL` is never updated.

Comment: the "cleaner look" alternative is the only one that works :)